# react native How to get child component const value to parent screen component

Tags: react-native

I have one text input in my child component and I want to get the text input data to my parent screen. I want to pass the data to one component to another component.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 components parent and child suppose , then it would be like

In render of Parent , basically you are passing a callback function to child

```
textChange = (value) => {
this.setState({newText:value});
}

render(){
return(
<Child onTextInput={this.textChange} />
)
}
```

and in child's render:

```
render(){
return(
<TextInput  onChangeText={e => this.props.onTextInput(e)}
)
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank You   onOk = () => {

    const selectedValue = this.treeRef.getSelectValue();
    // console.log(selectedValue)
    this.props.onComfirm(selectedValue);
    this.close();
  }

Comment: I want to pass the ''selectedValue'' to my parent component

Comment: this.props.onComfirm(selectedValue); yes , you can call a callback function like this